# Facebook Feed Without Link (Unity)

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

**Problem**

On iOS, using FB.Feed() without the "Link (optional)" param does not work and the error message is "FBSDKLog: FBShareDialogParams: only "http" or "https" schemes are supported for link thumbnails"

**Questions**

- Is the "Link" parameter not optional like the docs and InteractiveConsole scene say?
- If the "Link" param isn't set, the docs say the that the default value is: "The base URL of the posting application, as configured in the Developer App". Is it possible to not have this set even though our app has been live for months? Where is this setting? See image in "Current App Settings" below to see our current FB App settings. I thought the "App Domains" section was only for Canvas apps and not needed for iOS/Android-only apps.

**Additional Info**

- We have tried using Unity 4.3.0 and 4.3.3 and I have tried this with FB plugin 4.3.6 and beta 5.0.3 and it exhibits the same behavior in both. Interestingly, some older version of the FB plugin work without the URL.
- We are testing this using the InteractiveConsole. We make no changes (besides adding our AppId/Name) and build. I press "Open Feed Dialog" and it posts successfully. We then remove all text from the "Link (option)" text field and press "Open Feed Dialog" again and it does not work and gives the error message in the above "Problem" section.

**Current App Settings**
[image]

**Tests + Results**

See image below for results. Note that Test2 never shows up on my wall and when pressing "Post" in the Facebook app, the progress bar never goes blue and we get the error message described at the top under "Problem".

- Test1: Link, Link Name, Link Desc, Link Caption, Picture... + added text "Test1" on the Feed dialog
- Test2: Same as Test1 except no link... + added text "Test2" on the Feed dialog

[Test results](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60541766/FBTests.png)

Comment: Which platforms are you seeing this on?

Comment: iOS -- I haven't tested it on Android yet

Comment: I just tested it in the Editor with FB 5.0.3 and it DOES post successfully to my wall (however it doesn't appear to be consistent) without the Link param BUT it throws two errors a bunch of times when I click "Open Feed Dialog" with no text in the Link message. I'm not sure if they're related to the iOS issue... [Image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60541766/Screen%20Shot%202014-01-24%20at%2012.58.56%20PM.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we made a backend change a while back that disallowed empty feed posts.  So you'll have to provide a link, or an image, or the user will have to type something into the post.

Comment: Thanks for answering benp. I'm not trying to post an empty post. I try with an image but no link and it fails. I put text in with an image but no link, still fails. Text but no image or link, still fails.

Comment: benp - I added more information above in the "Tests + Results" section with an image that shows screenshots from two separate tests and the results.

Comment: @benp, that's only partly correctly.  The backend disallows link name,  link caption or link description without a link.  You still need to provide a link if you use those two.  It's optional otherwise.